# Spring Boot video chat

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, udp, video-streaming

I have task to create video chat which will allow to communicate two people witch each other. My architecture of application is: front-end 
**Angular 2/typescript**, backend: **java, spring boot** (and submodules). Everything works fine but I've got problem with understanding how to make video streaming. I was looking for any framework to do it but I've failed. As I understand WebSocket doesn't help me in this task and it's no appropriate to use it. Also as I understand Spring doesn't have any tool to solve the task. Is it really that I have to create streaming via clean UDP which exists in java or maybe there is another way, any framework which gives more higher interfaces for the task?

Comment: were you able to finish it up?

Comment: Yes, we have finished it.

Comment: can you tell us how you did it? what library did you use for spring boot?

Comment: Sorry for so long answer. We used NextRTC, but this was not very good idea, because we didn't have access to main classes and can't changed some important properties.
So my advice is to use WebRTC. We used this example [Ionic Video App](https://market.ionicframework.com/starters/video-and-text-chat-app-backend) and changed the code to our needs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magic keyword here is "WebRTC", which is the browser support to support Audio and Video **R**eal **T**ime **C**ommunication for **Web**.

Basicly the communication is happening peer 2 peer between the browsers of your users. The only thing your application is responsible of, is the signaling...to exchange the peer data for your clients.

Based on that, check out [this project called NextRTC](http://nextrtc.org/examples) for a reference.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I could't find documentation about API for NextRTC.
Could you provide us some documentation about NextRTC ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use agora rtc for group video chat and peer to peer video chat.but it will cost some money to use but we can use 10000 free minutes if the application in production better to use WEB real time connection

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).